# creating loop for jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery

```
/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `" . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns)) . "`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
$rResult = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
```

It is how specified in datatables...but my cindition is like this..

```
for($i==0;$i<count($val);$i++){
$con ='ID='.$val[$i];

$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `" . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns)) . "`
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
                $con 
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
        ";
$rResult = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
}
```

I have following questions :

1. Can I use like this or not ?
2. Will Data-tables support it ?
3. Or can we encode that array result?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are returning a JSON array of objects, or inner arrays, then DataTables will accept it just fine - see: http://datatables.net/blog/Extended_data_source_options_with_DataTables .

Also if you are using server-side processing, then you must adhere to the protocol required by DataTables, documented here: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side